# How to specify theorem styles (amsthm) should use bold equations (bm)?

Tags: amsmath, theorems, bold, boldmath, bm

From other questions on this site, I've come to the conclusion that `bm` is the easiest (best?) way to get bold equations.

I'm using `amsthm` to define a problem style, but the `\bfseries` doesn't make the equations bold, and adding `\bm` to the body font specification doesn't do it either.  I'd like a way to specify that equations in the problem style should be bold so I don't have to wrap it around every little equation.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}

\newtheoremstyle{parenbold} % Name
  {2\parskip}           % Space above
  {}                    % Space below
  {\itshape \bfseries}  % Body font
  {}                    % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}           % Theorem head font
  {}                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  {1em}                 % Space after theorem head
  {\thmname{#1 }\thmnumber{#2)}\thmnote{ [#3]}} % Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{parenbold}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem{probpart}{}
\renewcommand*{\theprobpart}{\alph{probpart}}

\begin{document}

\begin{prob}
    $\bm{H}$ and $\bm{K}$ are two subgroups of $\bm{G}$ of order $\bm{m}$ and $\bm{n}$ respectively.  Prove...
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Italics already give emphasis; boldface adds another level of emphasis. Too much like a punch in the eye, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I figured someone would mention that. ;) I've been playing around with it, regularly making changes. Italics on its own is barely distinguishable from regular text to my eye. Perhaps I just make everything simply bold, but then the thm body and thm head are identical, which isn't really what I want either. Bold by itself also looks too strong (brutish), and to my eye, bold italics (graceful) uses "less ink" and so gives an emphasis between bold and normal.

Fortunately I know how to make these changes on my own and can keep trying to tweak it until I find something that works best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bm` is for bold expressions in an otherwise normal weight math. To make all the math bold you should use `\boldmath` outside the math. So here you could use

```
 {\itshape \bfseries\boldmath}
```

as the body font specification.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  I don't quite follow your explanation though. What does "in an otherwise normal weight math" mean, and how is this different from `\boldmath`?

Comment: @TravisBemrose `\boldmath $a=b$` makes a bold a=b, bm is intended for `$a=\bm{b}$` making a bold b in a math expression that is otherwise non-bold.